# Giving text a background colour to match the width of text on each line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to give my text a background colour, simple enough but I have come into some difficulty.

Here's my html

```
<div class="hero_text">Screen Shot</div>
```

I needed to break this apart so that if there was a space, then the next word go onto a new line.

Here's my jquery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.hero_text').html(function(index, text) {
        return text.replace(' ', '<br>');
    });
});
```

Here's my css

```
.hero_text {
color: #FFF;
text-align: right;
background: green;
padding-left: 5px;
font-size: 30px;
display: inline;
float: right;
padding-right: 9px;
clear: both;
position: fixed;
right: 0;
bottom: 30%;
line-height: 30px;
}
```

Here's an image of what I'm getting at the moment

[image]

And here is what i'm trying to achieve

[image]

Notice the pink has got a little bit of padding to the left and right of the word but as the words are different length then the pink should be smaller and larger depending on the word?

Thanks

Comment: Why not just use a `<span>` to wrap the text within the `<div>`?

Comment: I can't do that, i have no access to the div to change it, unless it can be done using jquery?

Comment: This is why all text should be wrapped in appropriate text tags. Bare text nodes are hard to select and style.

Answer (score 1):

One approach, using jQuery to manipulate the HTML, is:

```
$('.hero_text').html(function (i,oldHTML){
    return oldHTML.replace(/\b([a-zA-Z]+)\b/g,'<span>$1</span>');
});
```

Coupled with the additional CSS:

```
.hero_text span {
    background-color: green;
    float: right;
    clear: right;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/NraU9/).

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the code, it works fine, but I noticed if I change the text i.e use a y in the second word, part of it over hangs the background colour, is it possible to have a padding-top on the first word and padding-bottom on the second to counter act this and still make it look good rather than put a padding top and bottom on both the words?

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps. I have updated the javascript in your code.[http://jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/karan3112/8scvj/1/)

```
var text_arr = $('.hero_text').text().split(' ');
$('.hero_text').html('');
for(i=0; i< text_arr.length; i++)
{
  $('.hero_text').append('<span class="text'+i+' clearfix">'+ text_arr[i] +'</span>');
}
```

Comment: OP has stated that the HTML cannot be changed. You might want to remove or edit before any downvotes come your way.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/S6sfu/

This is one without java script, will this do?

**HTML**

```
<div class="hero_text">Screen</div>
<div class="hero_text">Shot</div>
<div class="hero_text">A quick message</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.hero_text {
color: #FFF;
text-align: right;
background: green;
padding-left: 5px;
font-size: 30px;
display: inline;
float: right;
padding-right: 9px;
clear: both;
right: 0;
bottom: 30%;
line-height: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input but that is 3 divs, I have 2 words in 1 div

Answer (score 0):

You can split up the text into an array and than add the spans as you want. Somewhat like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var textArray=  $('.hero_text').html().split(' ');
    $('.hero_text').html('<span style="background: green;">'+textArray[0]+'</span><br>'+'<span style="background: green;">'+textArray[1]+'</span>');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following url: http://css-tricks.com/multi-line-padded-text/

Nearly all possible methods are supplied there.

If you don't have access to the html you could move the contents of the div to a span:
(Which is a VERY bad idea to begin with)

```
var $node = $('.hero_text');
var text = $node.innerHtml();
var $span = $('<span class="hero_text"></span>');
$span.appendTo($node.parent());
$node.remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you dont have access to div or the css** ,

---

this is the solution you can consider :

**UPDATED**

jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/P5LNx/7/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('.hero_text').html(function (index, text) {
        var bgcolor = $(this).css('background');
        $(this).css('background', 'transparent');
        var txt = text.split(' ');
        var content =  '<span style="background: ' + bgcolor + ';position:relative;">' + txt[0] + '</span><br>';
        content += '<span style="background: ' + bgcolor + ';">' + txt[1] + '</span>';
        return content;
    });
});
```

Steps :

1. Removed background of the div.
2. Added 2 `<span>` with same background as div
3. To `<span>`s, added your words (1 in each)

Comment: Hi thecbuilder, thanks for the code, it works fine, but I noticed if I change the text i.e use a y in the second word, part of it over hangs the background colour, is it possible to have a padding-top on the first word and padding-bottom on the second to counter act this and still make it look good rather than put a padding top and bottom on both the words?